# How do I stop a trigger from firing if the update is from a call to the REST API

Tags: apex

I have an application that is updating Salesforce by calling the REST API, and each time it updates the trigger on the object is fired.  I dont want to trigger to run on updates from the API, only from updates by users on Salesforce

Comment: does the client application have a running user that is never used for regular user interactions?

Comment: I've found this question for you that contains more information. Please take a look at that information, and if it doesn't answer your question, please let us know and we'll be glad to re-open your question after you [edit] it to explain how it is different than the other question and answers.